# using fill-height on a vuetify 2.x component

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have an app using `Vuetify (2.x)` grids where I am unable to get a component to fill the remaining height of the screen.

I have tried using the `fill-height` property for `v-row` however this only fills a fraction of the height of the screen:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-card elevation="2" class="pa-3">
            Row 1  
            </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      
      <v-row class="fill-height">
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-card elevation="2" class="pa-3">  
            Row 2
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-card elevation="2" class="pa-3">  
            Row 3
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>       
  </v-app>
</div>
```

What needs to be done to get **Row 2** to fill the rest of the available height of the screen?

https://codepen.io/deftonez4me/pen/LYZmOzy?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the flex utility classes like this...

```
<v-container class="grow d-flex flex-column flex-nowrap">
  <v-row class="shrink">
     <v-col cols="12">
      <v-card elevation="2" class="pa-3">
        Row 1  
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  
  <v-row class="grow">
     <v-col cols="12">
      <v-card elevation="2" class="pa-3 fill-height">  
        Row 2
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  
  <v-row class="shrink">
    <v-col cols="12">
      <v-card elevation="2" class="pa-3">  
        Row 3
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/LIb8hrlXuw)